# Best way to count number of records from NDB library

Tags: django, python-2.7, nosql, app-engine-ndb, google-app-engine-python

I am developing an application in which I am explicitly using memcache with Google Appengine's NDB library. I want something like this.

1) Get 100 records from datastore and put them in memcache.

2) Now whenever user wants these records I would get these records from memcache instead of datastore.

3) I would invalidate the memcache if there is a new record in datastore and then populate the memcache with 101 records.

I am thinking of an approach like I compare the number of records in memcache and datastore and if there is a difference, I would update the memcache.

But if we see documentation of NDB, we can only get count by retrieving all the records, and this is not required as datastore query is not being avoided in this way.

Any help anyone? Or any different approach I could go with?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than relying on counts, you could give each record a creation timestamp, and keep the most recent timestamp in memcache. Then to see if there are new records you just need to check if there are any timestamps newer than that, which assuming you have an index on that field is a very quick query.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I would give it a try.